# Don't delete a page if it holds users

Tags: functions, pages, users, hooks, actions

I have to do something but I just can't come up with a way to do it.
On one hand I have created pages who are companies. So every page is a company-page.
On the other hand I have created users who have a custom field added to their profile that holds the name of the company they work at.

No this is merely a connection between those two. So I came to the conclusion that if a company is deleted the users should be to, or at least a message should appear that the company can't be deleted because there are still users that are connected to the company.

I think I should hook in some sort of function to add an action to the page-delete button.

It's almost like if you delete a user and WP asks you if the posts the user has made are assigned to another user.

Can anybody tell me more about this or share some thoughts/ideas?

===================================
UPDATE
So I created the following for a custom_function to hook in the `before_delete_post`
NOTE: this is tested on a company page for output purposes. I use a `$_GET["company"]` request because the name is passed on in the URL.

```
global $post;
$company = $_GET['company'];
$employees = $wpdb->get_results("
             SELECT meta_value 
             FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
             WHERE meta_key = 'company' 
             AND meta_value='$company'"
             );

/* 
output $employees: 
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [meta_value] => company_name
    )
*/

if(in_array($company, $employees)){
    echo 'Yes';
}else{
    echo 'No';
}
```

Let's say I want to delete the page `company_name`. What I do is see if this name is in the `usermeta` table. If this is true the delete function should not be executed. If not the page can be deleted.

But this just keeps echo-ing `No` while it should echo `Yes` because I know the pagename is `company_name` and it is in the employee list. So I should have a match.

Comment: Where do you store user relations for a company? In another table or in post_meta?

Comment: The company is stored in the `posts` and `post_meta` tables. The users are stored in the `users` and `user_meta` tables. I added a field to the `user_meta` table that contains the exact same name as the page-name (this is the company name)

Comment: Try to create a WP_User_Query looking for company page name in users meta. In the official docs for meta query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Examples. In case if company names are not stored in a single record serialized. I did something similar, i solved this by storing connection on both sides. So users have a list which companies they belongs to, and companies which users they have. (company meta, user meta)

Comment: This is a way to do it. I like it. But how can I do this upon delete of a page?

Comment: Add an action, when deleting a post: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post You can do the check for relations. If it has any, you can abort the deletion and return with a message.

Comment: @Iamzozo Please see my update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives an array with objects. So `in_array()` won't find anything, you have to convert it before. After you get the results from wbdb:

```
$employees_array = array();
foreach($employees as $employee) {
    $employees_array[] = $employee->meta_value;
}

if(in_array($company, $employees_array)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be best solved by adding constraints in your database schemes. The best way to achieve this is by adding a foreign key constraint which reacts on the  "DELETE" action. 
For more info about the foreign key read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

You could also do a SELECT before calling the DELETE action and if it returns users exit the function with a error of some kind.

Comment: Wow this is (almost) a new one for me... I have never worked with constraints before. I first read up about constraints and then see if it fits my needs :-) . Thnx